# making a ClickEvent for vaadin NativeSelect

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to know if there's a way to make a ClickEvent for Vaadin NativeSelect in Eclipse!
I tried to do it with nativeSelect.addListener(), but didn't know how to do it and couldn't find a good sample or something helpful.

****UPDATED****

I want an event for the time that mouse clicked on the NativeSelect not when I change the value.(Something like MouseButtonDown or Something)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. [Selection components](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-selection.html#components.selection) usually have a [`ValueChangeListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-selection.html#datamodel.selection) which is triggered when you change the selected item(s). Is that what you're trying to do? If not please try to clarify your scenario. Additionally, it helps if you provide the Vaadin version you're using so people can provide appropriate code samples.

Comment: I want an event for the time that mouse clicked on the NativeSelect not when I change the value.(Something like MouseButtonDown or Something) @morfic

Comment: Do you want to handle a click in your implementation, or generate a click event for example from a JUnit-TestBench (or Selenium) test?

Comment: I want to generate a click event if I did understand it true. I want just one time in one codes scope make a ClickEvent, actually i'm new to java programming and also Vaadin, therefore i don't know if i am clear to tell what i'm looking for. @Morfic